# Limit Instagram php feed

Tags: php, api, feed, instagram

I'm looking for some helping with using a php instagram feed.

I found [this link](http://www.blueprintinteractive.com/blog/how-instagram-api-fancybox-simplified) through my research and it works perfectly but I don't know how to limit the results from instagram's default of 20.

I'd really just like to show 6 images at a time.

I'm not great with php so please forgive my ignorance.

Please see the code below

```
<?php
function fetchData($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $result;
}
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/ID-GOES-HERE/media/recent/?access_token=TOKEN-GOES-HERE");
$result = json_decode($result);
foreach ($result->data as $post) {
    // Do something with this data.
}
?>
```

Comment: Please note also that there is a recently (Nov 2015) introduced limit of 20 images for applications in sandbox mode. 
It took me forever to find that out because the top answers shown in Google don't mention this. So i am adding that now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify the number of images to return using the COUNT parameter. Try this:

```
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/ID-GOES-HERE/media/recent/?access_token=TOKEN-GOES-HERE&count=6");
```

If you are looking to retrieve a greater number of records and page through them on your side, check out the min_id and max_id for paging.

Answer (score 0):

Limit your loop

```
$items=6;

$i=0;

foreach ($result->data as $post) {

   if($i<$items){

      // Do something with this data.

   }
   else{

       break;

   }

   ++$i;
}
```